# Unable to get the Role using Context.User.IsRole

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, roles

I write the following code to access the page but this is not working for me

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (Context.User.IsInRole("DistrictAdmin"))
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

My Login check code

```
  string RoleTypeID;
    objLogin.UserName = txtUsername.Text;
    objLogin.Password = txtPassword.Text;

    if (objLogin.getRoles(out RoleTypeID))
    {
        Session["RoleID"] = RoleTypeID;
        FormsAuthenticationTicket oAuthTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUsername.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), false, RoleTypeID.ToString(), FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        string encryptoAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(oAuthTicket);


        HttpCookie oCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptoAuthTicket); // Name of auth cookie

        if (oAuthTicket.IsPersistent) oCookie.Expires = oAuthTicket.Expiration;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(oCookie);
        if (RoleTypeID == "DistrictAdmin" || RoleTypeID == "CampusAdministrator" || RoleTypeID == "LPACMember")
        {
            Response.Redirect("LEPstudentrecords.aspx");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblInvalid.Visible = true;
    }
```

and in my `web.config` i set as follows

```
     <roleManager enabled="false" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Default.aspx"
timeout="20" />
</authentication>

    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="180"></sessionState>
```

But i am unable to get the role even if he is authenticated can any one tell what to do

Here is the image after authenticated every thing is getting right but i am unable to access that page

[image]

Comment: Why is `roleManager enabled="false"` ???

Comment: Because i am getting the roles from my sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the role string as 'UserData' to the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`. There is no magic that will infer this value to a role.

I suggest you consult the documentation again.

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.formsauthenticationticket

See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/formsroleauth.aspx for an example without RoleManager.

Comment: Hi Leppie i didn't get you can you tell what changes should i made in my code

Comment: Look at the parameter where you are passing that role name in. It is NOT for role, it is for userdata.

Comment: Even if i remove that from my code and tried issue remains the same

Comment: That is completely expected. IIRC, you need to wrap the FormsIdentity into a GenericPricipal and assign that to `Context.User` if not using the builtin RoleManager.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have not configured the `RoleManager`. In your web.Config it is disabled.

```
<roleManager enabled="false" />
```

You need to use an exisiting RoleProvider or write your own.

Sample configuration

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleManager">
  <providers>
    <add name="SqlRoleManager" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
         connectionStringName="SqlRoleManagerConnection"
         applicationName="MyApplication" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Here are some links about role providers

[RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx)

[Implementing Custom Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx)

Comment: I am not using default roles i am using the user defined roles from my data

Comment: The `Context.User` is of type `RolePrinciple`. It uses the configured `RoleProvider` when you call the `IsInRole` method. So you need to write a custom role provider to use that method.